# What happens to the view.frame.size attribute after a CGAffineTransform (Rotate)?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, uiimageview, transform

I have a UIImageView that can be resized by pinching in and out (Example: view.frame.size.width+10). The image of the Image View can also be rotated (CGAffineTransformMakeRotate). **Okay, here is the problem**: When I resize the UIImageView AFTER having had applied a Rotate Transform the view resizes abnormally (inversly (shrink when it should grow, vice-versa) or at enormous resize unit increments). How can I resize my UIImageView in a consistent manner whether or not a CGAffineTransform is applied?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a warning in the documentation for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) that says, for the `frame` property:

> Warning: If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Use the `bounds` and `center` properties instead; they remain viable after a transform is applied.